# File chooser path-bar bug

Tags: pantheon-files, navigation

When I want to open an app the file chooser window pops up and as I navigate into a wrong folder and want to go back one step I click on the path-bar but it always takes me back to my home folder no matter where I click. Even if I try to edit the path by pressing ctrl+L and typing the location it still takes me back to my home folder.

Any ideas on what's going on or how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a bug report about this at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1165.  Hopefully it will be fixed by the next release.

Comment: As a work around you can use the keyboard shortcut `<Alt>Up` to navigate to the parent folder.